# Why does my static route within a nested dynamic route not work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a relatively simple pages/route structure, which is as follows:

```
\+---pages
|   |   contact.tsx
|   |   index.tsx
|   |   \_app.tsx
|   |   \_document.tsx
|   |  
|   +---game
|   |       \[slug\].tsx
|   |  
|   +---lists
|   |   ---create
|   |           new.tsx
|   |  
|   ---user
|       |   \[user\].tsx
|       |  
|       ---\[user\]
|           ---\[lists\]
|               |   \[list\].tsx
|               |  
|               ---edit
|                       index.tsx
```

With [user] and [lists] being dynamic routes, which access the database to retrieve some data.

The route "localhost:3000/user/admin20/lists/a-list-of-my-favorite-games/edit" results in a 404.
However, the route "localhost:3000/user/admin20/lists/a-list-of-my-favorite-games/" works as expected

my index.tsx file is a very simple react component without much in it:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Index() {
const router = useRouter();
const { user, list } = router.query;

    return (
        <div>index</div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Your route is accessible on http://localhost:3000/user/admin20/a-list-of-my-favorite-games/edit